# Pip устанавливает пакеты не в виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, linux, pip

На сервере стоит Ubuntu 16

Проблема такая:

1. Создал виртуальное окружение
2. Активировал его
3. Хочу установить туда что-нибудь через pip

   pip install package
4. Выскакивает ошибка о том, что я не могу это сделать, т.к. текущий пользователь не обладает достаточными правами.
5. Использую sudo:

   sudo pip install package

Пакет устанавливается не в виртуальное окружение, а в общий pip

Почему так происходит и что делать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншот покажите, что ли. Вдруг вы нас обманули и на самом деле не активировали)

Comment: Не обманываю) Скриншот приложил. Ну и просто поверьте, что если выйти из виртуального окружения, то там будет установлен Pillow 6

Comment: Мне кажется нужно на этапе №4 разобраться с проблемой, либо с самого начала получить привилегии рута (`sudo -s` например), и потом уже активировать окружение.

Comment: Покажите вывод команды pip без всяких sudo. С sudo совершенно очевидно, что оно установится глобально, потому что вы в этом случае запускаете глобальный pip, так что sudo нас не интересует

Comment: А ещё покажите вывод команды `ls -al venv/lib/`

Comment: вот вам очевидно, а я не знал, что sudo вызывает глобальный pip

Comment: sudo ради безопасности чистит всё своё окружение перед своей работой, для общего развития можете посмотреть, какой именно pip работает, с помощью команды `which pip` и сравнить его с `sudo which pip`

Comment: Спасибо, тогда попробую дать права текущему пользователю на редактирование папок, на которые он ругается без sudo. Глядишь все и решится. Я просто был уверен, что с sudo все должно быть не так)

Comment: Выводы команд вы так и не показали, но у меня есть подозрение, что вы создали виртуальное окружение рутом, и вот только рут и может его использовать (возможно `sudo ./venv/bin/pip install pillow` даже работает, но так делать не нужно)

Comment: у папки, в которой все происходило был владелец root. Не знаю почему. Сменил владельца на текущего юзера для папки и всего вложенного. Все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, назидательным голосом, в стотысячный раз: используйте полномочия суперпользователя только для **административных задач**. все остальные задачи выполняйте от имени рядового пользователя.